# How to ensure that a given process is NOT running, & terminate script if it is

Tags: powershell

I have a script wherein I stop (kill) a process. Immediately thereafter, I'd like some code to check if the process is indeed stopped, and if not, exit the script (and if it indeed is stopped, the script will of course continue.) Here's how I tried to do it:

```
if (Get-Process "notepad" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) {
    Write-Host "Program still running somehow, terminating script..."
    exit
}
else
{ Write-Host "Program stopped." }
```

I thought I had it figured out that the statement `(Get-Process "progname" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)` would eval to $true if there was one or more processes running (i.e. there was output returned), and $false if no output was returned (I specified the `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` to make sure there would be no output returned when there was not program found by that name.) It worked in testing when I ran this code block using a running program (say, "notepad"), and also when I tried a non-existant program (like say "notepadxxx".)

However, when I then integrated it into my larger program, and put it immediately after the line which terminates the program, as so:

```
Write-Host "Terminating Program..."
Stop-Process -Name "notepad" -Force
if (Get-Process "notepad" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) {
    Write-Host "Program still running somehow, terminating script..."
    exit
}
else
{ Write-Host "Program stopped." }
```

the `Get-Process` line evals to $true, and ends the script. Is this just a race condition between the `Stop-Process` line, and the subsequent `Get-Process` line, or is it a logic flaw? (and if so, what's the fix?)

Comment: possible duplicate of [powershell: synchronous stop-process](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4107581/powershell-synchronous-stop-process)

Comment: That's kinda what I want @neontapir, but this question is more about the test afterwords that ensures the process is indeed stopped before continuing on. So, I'd say not exactly a duplicate. However, I do appreciate the reference, and have incorporated it; but, I still am getting the logic problem :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this for the if condition:

```
if (Get-Process "notepad" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Where-Object {-not $_.HasExited })
```

Comment: This appears to work for me... tested with one and multiple instances for the program ("notepad" for testing.) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you're checking *too* immediately thereafter. The **if** statement is executed before the process has a chance to stop. When you use **Stop-Process**, it sends a stop signal to the command and moves on, it doesn't wait for the process to actually stop. Try adding `Sleep 1`, or even `Sleep .1`, between `Stop-Process [...]` and `if (Get-Process [...]`. Give it a moment to terminate before checking whether it did.

Comment: So I did try to make the Stop-Process wait by reforming the command line as `Stop-Process -Name "notepad" -Force -PassThru | Wait-Process` but when I test thereafter with `if ((Get-Process "notepad" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -ne $null) {` I'm still eval'ing to $true, since I get **Program still running somehow, terminating script...** as the output (and the script term's hitting the `exit`.)

Comment: Appears to be a race condition, by the way... If I put a `Start-Sleep -milli 300` in between the `Stop-Process` line and the `if` line, then the logic works.

Comment: But that's not what I suggested. **Wait-Process** won't work because **Stop-Process** doesn't manage/oversee the stopping of the process, it just sends a signal to the process to terminate. That was the whole point, that the invocation of **Stop-Process** is considered complete when it sends the instruction to the process, not when the process is actually stopped. Put `Sleep 1` in between the commands and I think you'll see that it works.

Comment: Oh...okay, you did try it, I hadn't refreshed the page. But I'll leave the comment as an explanation of why **Wait-Process** is subject to the same problem and doesn't make a difference.